# How to fix runtime error: load of null pointer of type 'const char

Tags: c

I need to write function which loads dictionary in hash table.I'm confused about error message: c:37:20 runtime error: load of null pointer of type 'const char', which runs in segmentation fault.

I've tried to change load function, but still didn`t help. And also tried to allocate memory for hashtable, as I thought problem might be in memory leaks.

```
`  // Represents number of buckets in a hash table
#define N 26

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Represents a hash table
node *hashtable[N];
// Hashes word to a number between 0 and 25, inclusive, based on its first letter
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // Allocates memory for hashtable
    int  *ht = malloc(26*sizeof(int));
    if(!ht)
    {
        unload();
        return false;
    }
    return tolower(word[0]) - 'a';  // this is error line 37:20
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{

    // Initialize hash table
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        hashtable[i] = NULL;
    }

    // Open dictionary
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        unload();
        return false;
    }

    // Buffer for a word
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Insert words into hash table
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        {
            // Allocate memory for node for each new word
            node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if (!new_node)
            {
                unload();
                return false;
            }
            // Copies word into node
            strcpy(new_node->word, word);
            new_node->next = NULL;
            // Hashes word
            hash(new_node->word);
            // Inserts word into linked list
            if(hashtable[i] == 0)
            {
                hashtable[i] = new_node;

            }
            else if(hashtable[i] == new_node)
            {
               new_node->next = hashtable[i];
               hashtable[i] = new_node;
            }
        }
    }

    // Close dictionary
    fclose(file);

    // Indicate success
    return true;
}
```

The function load should retun true when dictionary is loaded. But I get segmentation fault. Does it mean I didn't get right output from load function?

Comment: The thing that is missing: *which line is line 37*?

Comment: Sorry if there are any mistakes in my question.I'm using stack for first time))))  
 You can see it right in code                                                                              
 return tolower(word[0]) - 'a';  // this is error line 37:20

Comment: Additionally the code in question is not a [mcve] - what is the definition of `node` for example

Comment: Additionally `hash` returns a *value* that you'd probably want to store in a variable and use *later* yet I don't see any evidence to it - instead you discard the return value and use `i` later.

Comment: Here is definition of struct node and hashtable                                                   
 // Represents number of buckets in a hash table
#define N 26                                                                                                           maybe I malloc memoryfor hashtable  in a wrong way?

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Represents a hash table
node *hashtable[N];

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the information there. At least `word` is an array and not a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

> ```
>        new_node->next = NULL;
>        hash(new_node->word);
>        // Inserts word into linked list
>        if(hashtable[i] == 0)
>        {
>            hashtable[i] = new_node;
>
>        }
>        else if(hashtable[i] == new_node)
>        {
>           new_node->next = hashtable[i];
>           hashtable[i] = new_node;
>        }
> ```

you do not use the result of *hash()* and you use *i* rather than the hash result as index in *hashtable*, if *N* greater than 26 you read/write out of *hashtable*, in the other case you do not put the word in the right entry because the first at index 0, the next at index 1 etc whatever their first letter

Note `else if(hashtable[i] == new_node)` is never true and in fact never reach because `if(hashtable[i] == 0)` is always true because you limit the number of word to read

Must be something like that doing minimal changes

```
        int h = hash(new_node->word);

        // Inserts word into linked list
        if(hashtable[h] == 0)
        {
            hashtable[h] = new_node;
            new_node->next = NULL;
        }
        else 
        {
           new_node->next = hashtable[h];
           hashtable[h] = new_node;
        }
```

but in fact can be simplified to be :

```
        int h = hash(new_node->word);

        new_node->next = hashtable[h];
        hashtable[h] = new_node;
```

Note I suppose you do not read several times the same word (it is a dictionary)

---

To do

> ```
> while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
> ```

is dangerous because there is no protection if the read word is longer than LENGTH

supposing *LENGTH* is 32 do ( the word can store 32 characters more the final null character) :

```
while (fscanf(file, "%32s", word) == 1)
```

---

There is no reason to have the loop :

> ```
>    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
>    {
>     ...
>    }
> ```

remove it (but not its body of course), so :

```
while (fscanf(file, "%32s", word) == 1)
{
    // Allocate memory for node for each new word
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (!new_node)
    {
        unload();
        return false;
    }
    // Copies word into node
    strcpy(new_node->word, word);

    int h = hash(new_node->word);

    new_node->next = hashtable[h];
    hashtable[h] = new_node;
}
```

---

tte part

```
// Initialize hash table
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    hashtable[i] = NULL;
}
```

is useless because *hashtable* being global is initialized with 0

If you want to reload the dictionary you need to free the linked list before to reset to NULL

---

> memory leaks

the *malloc* in *hash* is useless and only create memory leaks, remove it :

```
// Hashes word to a number between 0 and 25, inclusive, based on its first letter
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    return tolower(word[0]) - 'a';
}
```

Warning if the first letter is not a-z or A-Z the return index is not a valid index for *hashtable*

---

For readability reason replace `#define N 26` by `#define N ('z' - 'a' + 1)`

---

A proposal adding missing definitions :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define bool int
#define true 1
#define false 0

// Represents number of buckets in a hash table
#define N ('z' - 'a' + 1)

// Represent max word length
#define LENGTH 32

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node * next;
}
node;

// Represents a hash table
node * hashtable[N];

// Hashes word to a number between 0 and 25, inclusive, based on its first letter
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
  return tolower(word[0]) - 'a';
}

// probable goal : empty hashtable 
void unload()
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
    while (hashtable[i] != NULL) {
      node * next = hashtable[i]->next;

      free(hashtable[i]);
      hashtable[i] = next;
    }
  }  
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
  // Open dictionary
  FILE * file = fopen(dictionary, "r");

  if (file == NULL)
    return false;

  // Buffer for a word
  char word[LENGTH + 1];

  // Insert words into hash table
  while (fscanf(file, "%32s", word) == 1)
  {
    if (isalpha(word[0])) {
      // Allocate memory for node for each new word
      node * new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));

      if (!new_node)
      {
        unload();
        return false;
      }

      // Copies word into node
      strcpy(new_node->word, word);

      int h = hash(new_node->word);

      new_node->next = hashtable[h];
      hashtable[h] = new_node;
    }
  }

  // Close dictionary
  fclose(file);

  // Indicate success
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 2)
    printf("Usage : %s <dictionary>\n", *argv);
  else if (!load(argv[1]))
    fprintf(stderr, "Error when loading '%s'\n", argv[1]);
  else {
    puts("dictionary content");

    for (size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
      node * n = hashtable[i];

      if (n != NULL) {
        printf("%c :", i + 'a');
        do {
          printf(" %s", n->word);
          n = n->next;
        } while (n != NULL);
        putchar('\n');
      }
    }

    unload();
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall d.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat d
alternate
bellow and
Below
dictionary
Hash main zombie
test
Zorro
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Usage : ./a.out <dictionary>
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out d
dictionary content
a : and alternate
b : Below bellow
d : dictionary
h : Hash
m : main
t : test
z : Zorro zombie
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out d
==2370== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2370== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2370== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2370== Command: ./a.out d
==2370== 
dictionary content
a : and alternate
b : Below bellow
d : dictionary
h : Hash
m : main
t : test
z : Zorro zombie
==2370== 
==2370== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2370==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2370==   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 13 frees, 5,872 bytes allocated
==2370== 
==2370== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2370== 
==2370== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2370== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, bruno!  But hashtable has 26 buckets only(leters of alphabet in ASCII,and than I'm supposed to use linked list(where I insert my nodes) And that`s the part of a task to use this hashfunction with return value only first letters. And I really don`t undarstand how to link nodes and hashtable bucket,which is array element, not pointer

Comment: @ksju yes, you implement a kind of hash table, so you have synonymous and to use a linked list for the synonymous is classical. If you take into account what I say in my answer it must be ok, and you are able to read any number of words (you are not limited to 26)

Comment: @ksju I missed to say you need to remove the `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++ )` (but not its body), because I suppose the goal if to only reference the words by their first letter

Comment: I also missed to say that this part of code is CS 50 task, and some code is defalt, as hash function, node and hashtable declaration, for example, and I can't change it formula(hashing only first letter). but I'm confused about fact that error messege is in their (CS50) code not mine

Comment: @ksju no problem except the naming _hash_ which doesn't not really correspond to the goal of the function. If you do the changes I speak about your program must work. I edited my answer to add a full definition more execution examples